# How can I get the parent of a view using uiautomator?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to identify the parent view of an ui element so I can navigate through the UI freely.

For example, in Settings app, I can find the view with the text "Bluetooth":

```
UiObject btView = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Bluetooth"));
```

Now, the part where I get stuck is this one: I want to navigate two levels up and start a new search for the on/off button that enables and disables bluetooth.

Note: I can get the button if I use the code below.

```
UiObject btButtonView = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.Switch").instance(1));
```

This searches for switch buttons and returns the second encounter. I want the search to be more precise and look for the button in the linear layout that contains the "Bluetooth" text.

UPDATE:
This is the layout of the Settings app (the Bluetooth part that I need):

```
LinearLayout
    LinearLayout
        ImageView
    RelativeLayout
        TextView (with text = "Bluetooth")
    Switch ()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to find the UiObject two levels up first using the text. This can be done using the `getChildByText()` methods in UiCollection or UiScrollable. Then you can easily find the switch. For 'Settings' this code works on my device:

```
UiScrollable settingsList = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
UiObject btItem = settingsList.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(LinearLayout.class.getName()),"Bluetooth", true);

UiObject btSwitch = btItem.getChild(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Switch.class.getName()));
btSwitch.click();
```

Comment: This method does not work either. The UiObject two levels up is a LinearLayout, but it does not have the text attribute. So I can't identify it by the text "Bluetooth". Updated the question with the actual layout of the app.

Comment: It does work. You don't identify by the text of the LinearLayout. "It looks for any child matching the childPattern argument that has a child UI element anywhere within its sub hierarchy that has a text attribute equal to text." In other words, you look for a LinearLayout that has a child with the text Bluetooth.

Comment: Yes, it works. It seems I did something wrong the first time.

Comment: Why is the parent element identified as scrollable? I thought it was a LinearLayout element

Answer (score 4):

Below code works for me.

```
//Getting the scrollable view

UiScrollable settingsList = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));

for (int i=0; i<=settingsList.getChildCount(new UiSelector ().className(LinearLayout.class.getName())); i++) {
//Looping through each linear layout view
UiObject linearLayout = settingsList.getChild(new UiSelector().className(LinearLayout.class.getName()).instance(i));

//Checking if linear layout have the text. If yes, get the switch, click and break out of the loop.
if (linearLayout.getChild(new UiSelector ().text("Bluetooth")).exists()) {
    UiObject btSwitch = linearLayout.getChild(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Switch.class.getName()));
    btSwitch.click ();
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for Looping through  linear layout soultion! that worked fine for me !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just search for ON/OFF slider -> You can directly search for bluetooth OFF/ON button and click on it to disable/enable bluetooth -

You can check screenshot of the bluetooth page(using command - uiautomatorviewer) in command prompt and see that OFF button will have text in  the OFF/ON slider. Then simply use -

```
   new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("OFF")).click();
```

Comment: I can identify the button using its class name. I just select the second instance of that ui object. I wanted to search for a ui element in the parent view of an element which can be identified 100%, no matter what my layout is at one point.

So, the question still is: how can I identify the parent of an ui elemen?

Answer (score 0):

recently found that we could use getFromParent (for UiObject) and fromParent (for UiSelector) to select an uncle of object for example.
If we have such layout:

```
`LinearLayout
    relative layout
        text View
    relative layout
        check box`
```

we could get checkbox from textview with this code:

```
TextViewTitle().getFromParent(new UiSelector()
            .fromParent(new UiSelector()
                    .resourceId("android:id/checkbox")));
```

where TextViewTitle is a Uiobject with text view

Comment: but we could use UiObject2 with BySelector

Answer (score 0):

`uiautomator` not support: get parent node directly

But you can add it by yourself (which need many work)

General steps:

1. add `xpath` for `uiautomator`

   - can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281021/how-to-create-xpath-with-the-help-of-uiautomator-for-android-app)
2. using `xpath` to locate parent node `d.xpath("/current_node_path/..")`

Additional Node:

I use

- [uiautomator2](https://github.com/openatx/uiautomator2#xpath)

  - `uiautomator2` is based on [xiaocong/uiautomator](https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator)

    - [xiaocong/uiautomator](https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator) based on [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html)

to successfully find parent node by:

`self.driver.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Contact']/..")`

and full code:

```py
    def isMatchNode(self, curNodeAttrib, toMathInfo):
        isAllMatch = True
        for eachKey, eachToMatchValue in toMathInfo.items():
            if eachKey not in curNodeAttrib:
                isAllMatch = False
                break

            curValue = curNodeAttrib[eachKey]
            if curValue != eachToMatchValue:
                isAllMatch = False
                break


        return isAllMatch


    def findParentNode(self, curNodeXpath, matchDict, maxUpLevel=3):
        matchNode = None

        curNode = self.driver.xpath(curNodeXpath).get()
        curNodeAttrib = curNode.attrib # .attrib contain 'clickable'
        # curNodeInfo = curNode.info # .info not contain 'clickable'
        isCurMatch = self.isMatchNode(curNodeAttrib, matchDict)
        if isCurMatch:
            # current is match
            matchNode = curNode
        else:
            # try parent nodes
            curUpLevel = 1
            curParentNodeXpath = curNodeXpath
            hasFound = False
            while((not hasFound) and (curUpLevel <= maxUpLevel)):
                curParentNodeXpath += "/.."
                curParentNode = self.driver.xpath(curParentNodeXpath).get()
                curParentNodeAttrib = curParentNode.attrib
                isCurParentMatch = self.isMatchNode(curParentNodeAttrib, matchDict)
                if isCurParentMatch:
                    matchNode = curParentNode
                    break


        return matchNode


    def location_WexinAdd(self, reload=False):
        for eachNodeText in ["Contact", "Public Account"]:
            eachNodeXpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@text='%s']" % eachNodeText
            matchDict = {"clickable": "true"}
            clickableParentNode = self.findParentNode(curNodeXpath=eachNodeXpath, matchDict=matchDict)
            if clickableParentNode:
                clickableParentNode.click()
            else:
                logging.warning("Fail click %s for not found clickable=true (parent) node", eachNodeText)
```

for your refer.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should use UiObject2. It's much easier to get the ascendant hierarchy with it than with UiObject.

Here's a solution with UiObject2:

```
val labelText: UiObject2 = device.wait(Until.findObject(By.text("Bluetooth")
            .clazz("android.widget.TextView")), 2000)

val checkboxView = labelText.parent.parent.findObject(By.clazz("android.widget.Switch"))
```