# How to find parent element of already known child element in Appium Python?

Tags: python, xpath, appium, element, parent

Child element does not have proper xpath or id. But it has text attribute with value "Hi'. Xpath does not contain any expected text. It just contains hierarchy of elements and their positions. So I have used ui_automator with text.

```
1. child_ele = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("Hi"))
2. parent_ele = child.ele.find_element_by_xpath("..")
```

The above code throws **"Element not found exception in line 2"**

I have used python debugger to try several combos of xpath. So, it's not even related to explicit wait to assume if it is loading related.

Tried this in  Appium Desktop 1.17.0
Please suggest any working solution. 
Thanks!

Comment: You should probably read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680352/how-can-i-get-the-parent-of-a-view-using-uiautomator